# toroidal compactifications of moduli spaces of ppav

Tags: algebraic-geometry, moduli-space, toric-geometry, compactification

Are the modular toroidal compactifications of ppav's (second Voronoi) defined by Alexeev without self-intersections? i.e. are the irreducible component of the boundary divisor normal? If not, can one find another toroidal compactification (possibly dominating the second Voronoi) that is?

Thanks!